# Cassandra: Get metadata using keyspace and table name

Tags: triggers, cassandra, metadata

I'm creating a custom trigger for casssandra.

So, to get the metadata, the statement in the given [example trigger file fails.](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java)

```
 TableMetadata metadata = Schema.instance.getTableMetadata(auditKeyspace, auditTable);
```

I get this error while build

```
AuditTrigger.java:27: error: package org.apaceh.cassandra.schema does not exist
[javac] import org.apaceh.cassandra.schema.TableMetadata;
[javac]                                   ^
[javac] /home/bkoganti/cassandra/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] import org.apache.cassandra.schema.Schema;
[javac]                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Schema
[javac]   location: package org.apache.cassandra.schema
[javac] /home/bkoganti/cassandra/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         TableMetadata metadata = Schema.instance.getTableMetadata(auditKeyspace, auditTable);
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class TableMetadata
[javac]   location: class AuditTrigger
[javac] /home/bkoganti/cassandra/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java:50: error: package Schema does not exist
[javac]         TableMetadata metadata = Schema.instance.getTableMetadata(auditKeyspace, auditTable);
[javac]                                        ^
[javac] 4 errors
```

There is no class TableMetadata and Schema available.

So, how do I get the metadata using the keyspace name and table name.

Comment: first off, are you really really sure you want triggers? this is not the same as relational db triggers and have some complex corner cases

Comment: Yes! I'm actually a student, not for development. I would want to explore it. :)

Comment: can you include your maven/gradle/ant/ivy or whichever dependancies you include?

Comment: No, I haven't included any dependencies. I just cloned the project(https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers). Edited my auditTrigger file and ran ant jar. When I remove the statement the code compiles and a jar file is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo missed during some refactors. I created a jira and provided patch with fix here [CASSANDRA-13796](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13796) you can see the change [on github](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/pull/140/files#diff-7053335188e9d09b1dbd1d1ddd1d4fbdR48)

```
     audit.row()
          .add("keyspace_name", update.metadata().keyspace)
-         .add("table_name", update.metadata().table)
+         .add("table_name", update.metadata().name)
          .add("primary_key", update.metadata().partitionKeyType.getString(update.partitionKey().getKey()));
```

Comment: Adding to this, there is no TableMetadata and Schema class available in org.apache.cassandra.schema package. Schema class now exists in org.apache.cassandra.config. The line can be changed to PartitionUpdate.SimpleBuilder audit = PartitionUpdate.simpleBuilder(Schema.instance.getCFMetaData(auditKeyspace, auditTable),
                                                                            UUIDGen.getTimeUUID());